# use variable while writing equations in tex. loop over the variable to write different equations

Tags: python, python-3.x, latex, tex

I am using tex to write equations in python. And the equations I am writing are repetitive. as in, only one variable in the equation is changing and it is incrementing by a constant number each time. Is there a way to introduce a variable in the equation (text) so, that I can loop over the variable to write equations and save space and time?

```py
self.add(TexMobject(r"cos(\frac{2\pi}{6}) + i sin(\frac{2\pi}{6})"))
```

here I want to change 2 in the numerator to 4,6,8..12.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Sure. Use a `for` loop and f-strings. (You can look up both concepts online or read a Python book.)

Answer (score -1):

well, maybe.
(10 is changable)

```
for x in (10)
  a = x * 2
  self.add(TexMobject(r"cos(\frac{" + a + "\pi}{6}) + i sin(\frac{" + a + "\pi}{6})"))
```

Comment: This is not Python.

Comment: oh sorry, i think i'm too used to doing javascript

Comment: did i fix it? (I hope...)